#  Function extension  in a Sobolev space

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

Let  $\Omega$ be a domain of  $R^n$ and let  $H^2(\Omega)$ be the usual Sobolev space.

Let $\emptyset\ne \omega_1\subset\omega_2$ be open subsets of $\Omega$, and let $\theta \in H^2(\omega_1)$.

I am wondering  about the existence of a function  $\tilde{\theta} \in H^2(\Omega)$ such that :

1) $\tilde{\theta}=\theta$ on $\omega_1$,

2) $\tilde{\theta} $ is constant on $\Omega-\omega_2$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes,  with the caveat indicated in the comment below.  Consider an arbitrary extension  $\hat{\theta}\in H^2(\Omega)$. Now choose a compactly supported smooth function $\eta$ such that

$${\rm supp}\;\eta\subset \Omega\setminus \omega_2,\;\;\eta\equiv 1 \;\;\mbox{on $\omega_1$}. $$

The function $\tilde{\theta}=\eta\cdot \hat{\theta}$ has  the properties you asked for.

Comment: Provided that the function $\theta \in H^2(\omega_1)$ has a Sobolev-extension to begin with.

Comment: If there is no extension, then the  answer is obviously negative. However extensions do exist under mild regularity assumption. See e.g.  Adams' book on Sobolev spaces.